# Maven module jar missing

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've got a multi-modules maven project and I'm trying to add a module to my project. I know a lot of questions have been asked but it didn't solved my problem. When I deploy my project, the .jar of my new module is not registered whereas my others modules are working properly.
I've added the new module in the pom of my parent module in my dependency management:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.33-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>base</module>
        <module>mynewmodule</module>
        </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>base</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>mynewmodule</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

About the pom of the new module, I've specified the packaging to jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.33-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mynewmodule</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've also done a maven `build project`.

I don't understand then why when I deploy my project with Jenkins, the jar of my new module is missing. Have I missed something?

Comment: Are you able to see the jar file of new module inside target folder ?

Comment: Inside the target folder of my new module I've got the folders `classes` and `test-classes`(I don't know where to find the jar actually). It's the same as the other modules which are deployed properly. I don't find any `.jar` file.

Comment: It means, the module is not built properly. In case of multi module maven project, each module must have a jar file inside target folder.

Comment: what does "when I deploy my project with Jenkins" do exactly? You added a dependency from newmodule to base. If the job existed before and deploys base nothing really changed, other than there is a jar created that is not picked up automatically by jenkings. The jar should be in the target folder if you run "mvn install" without errors.